# How can I conditionally reference an entity?

Tags: entities

I would like to have an inline entity reference form that will optionally provide a write-in text form if the entity doesn't already exist. Here's the use case: I want to reference a faculty profile that is associated with a particular research project; but I want the option to also associate another person who does not have a profile on the site. In a corresponding view, if the associated person has a profile on the site, their name will link to their profile, otherwise it will simply appear without a link.

Comment: What do you mean by associate? By username?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Entity reference](https://drupal.org/project/entityreference) module to insert the references of the existing users to the content type.

> This project provides D7 versions of the 'node_reference' and
>   'user_reference' field types, that were part of the CCK package in D6,
>   at functional parity with the D6 counterparts.

For the rest of the users, you could use a textfield.

Comment: Yes, that's what I've done. I currently have three fields, one for the entity reference, one for the text field, and a third Boolean field that asks whether users would like to add an external participant. The second and third fields are dependent, so that the text field only appears on the form if the user checks the box for "Add an external participant." This works, but I don't find it very elegant, so I thought I'd ask for other people's input on this question. Thanks!